# Couchdb 3.2.2 does not start on boot after instaltion

Tags: couchdb

I had installed the couchdb 3.2.1. The service started automatically on server boot. After upgrading automatically to 3.2.2 all went wrong and i removed 3.2.1 and made a fresh install of 3.2.2. All is working except the start of the service if the server boots. What can i do to fix this? Thank you.

EDIT:
Following the suggestion of Honeywild, i confirm that the service is enabled. I reboot the server and the couchdb did not started again. In the log appeared this:

```
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.718192Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3835.0> -------- OS Process died with status: 143
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.719167Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3894.0> -------- OS Process died with status: 143
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.838879Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3835.0> -------- gen_server <0.3835.0> terminated with reason: {exit_status,143}
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.839013Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3835.0> -------- gen_server <0.3835.0> terminated with reason: {exit_status,143}
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.839087Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3894.0> -------- gen_server <0.3894.0> terminated with reason: {exit_status,143}
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.839171Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3894.0> -------- gen_server <0.3894.0> terminated with reason: {exit_status,143}
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.843963Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3835.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3835.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {exit_status,143} at gen_server:handle_common_reply/8(line:805) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:226); initial_call: {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.3834.0>], message_queue_len: 0, links: [<0.279.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 28, reductions: 5062
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.844450Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3835.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3835.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {exit_status,143} at gen_server:handle_common_reply/8(line:805) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:226); initial_call: {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.3834.0>], message_queue_len: 0, links: [<0.279.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 28, reductions: 5062
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.844742Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3894.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3894.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {exit_status,143} at gen_server:handle_common_reply/8(line:805) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:226); initial_call: {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.3893.0>], message_queue_len: 0, links: [<0.279.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 28, reductions: 8319
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.845669Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.3894.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3894.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {exit_status,143} at gen_server:handle_common_reply/8(line:805) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:226); initial_call: {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.3893.0>], message_queue_len: 0, links: [<0.279.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 28, reductions: 8319
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.867452Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.549.0> -------- gen_server <0.549.0> terminated with reason: killed
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.867542Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.549.0> -------- gen_server <0.549.0> terminated with reason: killed
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.867706Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.549.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.549.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: killed at gen_server:decode_msg/9(line:475) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:226); initial_call: {couch_multidb_changes,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.431.0>,couch_replicator_sup,<0.397.0>], message_queue_len: 0, links: [], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 2586, stack_size: 28, reductions: 12699
[error] 2022-04-26T12:49:53.867823Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.549.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.549.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: killed at gen_server:decode_msg/9(line:475) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:226); initial_call: {couch_multidb_changes,init,['Argument..
```

Then i simple run service couchdb start, and it started without any problem.
This kind of problems did not occur in previous couchdb version and usually i simple made upgrade without any problems. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS.
Any more ideas? Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an update from couchdb that fixed the problem: now version is 3.2.2-2 in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if the systemctl service is enabled, run systemctl is-enabled

`sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep couchdb`

or

`sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled | grep couchdb`

if the output to a console will be empty, run:

`sudo systemctl enable couchdb.service`

then check again:

`sudo systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled | grep couchdb`

next, if the service has been enabled, you did right, you followed a good practice, which is to identify the error in the logs.

Probably you tried:

```
sudo journalctl -u couchdb.service
```

and then you found the error which you mentioned above.

Further research steps can include:

1. Disable the systemd service (temporary): `systemctl disable couchdb`
2. Reboot
3. Run the application manually not as a systemd service `/path/to/couchdb` and check a result.
4. Run the application manually with strace `strace /path/to/couchdb`and check a result.

One more idea:

You have to be sure that the service is started after the network is started

More:

agree and conduct a diagnostic session together to understand what exactly causes this error.

Comment: It is enabled. I edit my question to post some more information after your suggestion.

Comment: probably the solution is associated with gen_server:  ```killed at gen_server:decode_msg/9(line:475)```

what is done on line 475 and what is decode_msg